# How to make autocomplete in Emacs appear in another window?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Using CEDET, everytime it autocompletes after a member selection "." or ">", another buffer overrides the current one. I find it really annoying.

Also, how can I use page up/page down with the small buffer of auto-complete mode?

Answer (score 2):

For your #1, consider filing an Emacs bug report (CEDET is now part of vanilla Emacs), using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The Emacs developers will determine whether the behavior really represents a bug (or an enhancement request).